# Ajuda com tkinter no python, Button e Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Estou a alguns dias aprendendo orientação a objeto e aprendendo sobre a interface grafica do tkinter, as coisas basicas estava dominando, contudo queria tentar fazer uma simples calculadora e me deparei com o "input" deles o tal do metodo e nele não sei com faço pra converter em uma variavel, tentei usar o metodo get() e etc mas não funcionou, tentando checar também o botão que deveria servir pra registrar os numeros escritos, vejo que ele assim que o progama inicia funciona dando a resposta: '','' ja que estavam vazias as caixas de resposta e não volta a funcionar, como se o comando fosse executado apenas uma vez sem nem precisar meu clique

OBJETIVO FINAL: ------------------ CALCULADORA DE SOMA SIMPLES-------------------------------------------

---

### Codigo incia aqui:

```
insira o código aqui
```

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class app():
def init(self):
self.root = root self.tela()
self.frames_da_tela()
self.botoes()
root.mainloop()

```
    def tela(self):
        root.title("Calculadora de Matemática")
        root.geometry("500x500")
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.configure(background='lightblue')


       def frames_da_tela(self):
          self.frame1 = Frame(self.root, bg='darkblue')
          self.frame1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.15)
          self.frame2 = Frame(self.root, bg='darkblue')
          self.frame2.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.15)
          self.frame3 = Frame(self.root, bg='grey')
          self.frame3.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.15)
          self.lb1 = Label(self.frame3, text='', font=("Arial", 14))
          self.lb1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.4)

     def botoes(self):
          self.codigoentry1 = Entry(self.frame1, font=("Arial", 15))
          self.codigoentry1.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.6)
          self.codigoentry2 = Entry(self.frame2, font=("Arial", 15))
          self.codigoentry2.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.6)
          self.bt1 = Button(self.root, text="Somar", font=("Arial", 14), 
          command=self.somar_recebidos())
          self.bt1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1)
     def somar_recebidos(self):
         self.soma = self.codigoentry1.get(), self.codigoentry2.get()
         print(self.soma)
```

app()

Comment: Importante editar a primeira versão que fez da pergunta e fornecer um [mcve] do problema no lugar do código aplicado (como já orientado). Para evitar duplicação de informações o espaço de comentários está desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na postagem original.